# Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void getUserName() from the type UserInfo

Tags: apex, user, execute-anonymous, userinfo

I dont know what is the problem. When I am trying to use UserInfo.getUserName() in my main org it doesnt work and gives me error like in title, but in another org it works perfectly. What can I do? So maybe there are some settings enabled?

```
UserInfo.getUserName()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error, in respect to standard library methods, is always a result of [name shadowing](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_name_shadowing.htm#:%7E:text=Member%20variables%20in%20one%20class,and%20written%20by%20different%20teams.), assuming you have the correct parameters; the only other time you should get this error is if you have the wrong number or data types of parameters (e.g. passing in a String when an Integer is expected).

Basically, you have either a variable, class, or interface named `UserInfo` (case insensitive) in the org where you're having the problem. The fix is to either (a) refactor or remove the `UserInfo` class/variable/interface so it's no longer conflicting, or (b) use `System.UserInfo.getUserName()` instead, which is always guaranteed to reference the library method, since `System` is a [reserved keyword](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_reserved_words.htm).

As a matter of practicality, I advise refactoring over using the `System` namespace, because this is likely to come up over and over again as more developers work on your code.

Comment: Thanks. Got mixed up with orgs and packages.